# Playing with buttons in C#.net using visual-studio

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

Well it's not playing actually.
  I have a database with  about 200 list of items in it.  I've used DataTable to fetch all the data in single connection.

Then created a windows button that creates new button for all the items.

It is OK and I was able to do it easily.

But I stuck over two things..
First is, I have limited space in my windows form, that's why I want to load only 30 buttons at first and then upon second click event, I want to load buttons for remaining 30 items and so on..

Second problem is, even if i managed to solve the first problem? How to arrange them in proper row/column?

Please help.

Comment: Why you want 200 buttons in the first place? What/why do you want to show?

Comment: @PoweRoy: These 200 buttons are for food items for a restaurant that will have individual action in it?

Comment: isn't it better to organize the items in categories so you need less buttons. This will help in a clear overview for the user.

Comment: these 200 items are categorized in category A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you take a [`DataGridView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e0ywh3cz.aspx) with a [`BindingSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.aspx) and a [`DataGridViewButtonColumn`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewbuttoncolumn.aspx)? With this as a starting point you can simply glue them together by calling:

```
myDataGridView.DataSource = myBindingSource;
myBindingSource.DataSource = myDataTable;
```

#### Update

Surely you can try to do the whole visualization on yourself by using a `TableLayoutControl`. But the `DataGridView` is a control that is specialized to visualize data in a data grid (hence the name of it).

The grid view is a very complex control, but it has a lot of nice features which make your results looking more professional by simply configuring some properties of it. For example simply set the property `AutoSizeColumnsMode` to `Fill` to simply avoid horizontal scroll bars and set the Column.AutoSizeMode of some columns to e.g. `DisplayedCells` to enforce which columns should be wrapped, etc.

Also there are a lot of features regarding to data validation, formatting, etc. So i think even if the step-in hurdle is a little higher you got a much better visualization then trying to do all this stuff manually by taking a TableLayoutPanel. Last but not least there are lots of examples about how to use the specific properties within the MSDN and if you get really stuck just search for the problem here on SO or on the web and if you don't find a proper solution just ask a question here on SO.

Comment: I figured out another way using TableLayout... which one must i choose?

Answer (score 1):

Grab an ordered list of records, split it to a list of "pages" (which is also a list of records) and use navigation buttons to change the context of current page.